# powershell: copy date from XML and create a new file

Tags: powershell

I have an XMLs with a mask XXXXX-sell-XXXXX.xml, code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <id>document-20210301-sell</id>
  <number>1</number>
  <type>a1</type>
  <id>document-20210301-sell</id>
  <number>2</number>
  <type>a1</type>
  .....
</document>
```

I want to copy the newest XML to another folder adding date taken from XML in filename with a mask:

yyyymmdd-sell.xml

My code is not doing a job:

```
$path1="C:\sell\"
$path2="c:\sell\in\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path1 -Filter "*-sell-*" |
Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
Sort-Object -Property CreationTime |
Select-Object -Last 1 |

[xml]$xml = Get-Content 
$date = $xml.document | Where-Object {$_.id -like "*20210301*"}
Copy-Item -Destination $path2 -PassThru |
Rename-Item -NewName {$Date + "-sell".xml"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, mcq. This might work, sometimes pipes make things complicated:

```
$path1="C:\sell\"
$path2="c:\sell\in\"

$f = Get-ChildItem -Path $path1 -Filter "*-sell-*" |
  Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
  Sort-Object -Property CreationTime |
  Select-Object -Last 1

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $f
$date = $xml.document.id[0]
#
# get date like yyyymmdd:
#
if($date -match "\d+") {
  $date = $matches[0];  
}

#
# copy and rename:
#
Copy-Item $f -Destination $path2 -PassThru |
  Rename-Item -NewName ($date + "-sell.xml")
```

With $date -match "\d+", \d is regex (Regular Expression) symbol representing any digit in [0-9] (from 0 to 9), "+" means more than 1 digit, in our case 8 for yyyymmdd numerical value, we capture the date substring in .id value, such as 20210301, 20190925, ...

Please also consult https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1 to start.

Comment: Thanks but still facing pipeline problems:

 [xml]$xml= Get-Content $f
+ ~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline

Comment: Please suppress in your code the pipe sign after -Last 1

Comment: OK, I removed pipe after -Last 1 and it went through. However, there is another problem: 
Problem 1: 
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\sell\12112-sell-110011.xml' because it does not exist.
At C:\sell\test.ps1:12 char:8
+ $xml = Get-Content $f
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\sell\12112-sell-110011.xml:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: Problem 2: Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\sell\test.ps1:13 char:1
+ $date= $xml.document.id[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: Please make a test on Powershell console with command Get-Content C:\sell\12112-sell-110011.xml to see if you can read it?

Comment: Yes, Get-Content reads it from a console. Maybe there should be additional parameter with path for get-content?

Comment: I tested the code shown above on my console with test1.ps1, all works. Get-Content requires no more parameter then the file path. Please show your code used again to see problem.

Comment: I see where the problem might be. My user has some limitations in C:\sell so I am trying to run a script in different folder: C:\test\ . It means that script is in different folder than target XMLs. For that particular case, should it be somehow changed in script where the path of script is diffrent than XML path?

Comment: The best way might be to change rights on  C:\sell for your users access. I've no accurate idea.

Comment: OK, I am copying files to other directory and then doing a job so it worked. The only problem is with reading date by: if($date -match "\d+") {
  $date = $matches[0];  - can you write how it works? Because it takes only letter "d" and put it as $date in the name.